# Changing order of columns for a table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a bigquery table with schema as :

```
CREATE TABLE `abc`
(
col2 STRING,
col1 DATE,
col3 STRING,
);
```

and after creating and loading months worth of data in it, I realised I want the DDL to look like,

```
CREATE TABLE `abc`
(
col1 DATE,
col2 STRING,
col3 STRING,
);
```

I want this change because the upstream ETL code expects it in this way.

Is there a way to achieve this?

PS: drop and create the table isn't an option as it has important data.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You won't miss any data. Try this.

```
create or replace table <SCHEMA.NEW_TABLE_NAME> as 
select col1,col2,col3  from <SCHEMA.OLD_TABLE_NAME>;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you make the select you can pass the order you want for your columns.

Instead of selecting it like `SELECT * FROM ...`

just do it as `SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM ...`