# BigQuery - Add column to existing table

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In GCP BigQuery, Can we add a column to an existing table and change his order in the table ?

for the moment I found only one way which is to delete the table modify the JSON of the table and recreate it with the new column in the right place

Do you have a solution please?

Comment: Did you check : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas ? First thing in the documentation is how to add a new column in various ways. Console, SQL, Python, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Add column using SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE mydataset.mytable
ADD COLUMN new_column STRING;
```

Source: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#sql

Change order of columns:

```
create or replace table <SCHEMA.NEW_TABLE_NAME> as 
select col1,col2,col3  from <SCHEMA.OLD_TABLE_NAME>;
```

Source: [Changing order of columns for a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68843791/changing-order-of-columns-for-a-table)